# Wordpress use template

Tags: plugin-development

I'm working with a custom plugin that will create virtual pages using regex. I'm trying to figure out how to tell my custom pages to use a certain template from the theme. How would I go about that?

Comment: A sample of your code with `// insert template here` would help, even pseudo code chunks to understand your flow.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [single_template](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/single_template) or [template_include](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) filters would help you achieve the result you want?

You can use either of those filters to change which template WordPress loads for your content.